# Changing length of column to fit entire string in fpdf

Tags: php, html, html-table, fpdf

[image]

how do I change the length of the column to fit all the characters of each cell?

Tried using dynamic lengths but didn't help out much,

using FPDF function to get this table and the table contents are from database..

Code for creating the table

```
function LoadData($file)
{
// Read file lines
/*$lines = file($file);
$data = array();
foreach($lines as $line)*/
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($file))
$data[] =array_values($row);
return $data;
}
// Simple table
function BasicTable($header, $data)
{
// Header
foreach($header as $col)
    $this->Cell(40,7,$col,1);
$this->Ln();
// Data
foreach($data as $row)
{
    foreach($row as $col)
        $this->Cell(40,6,$col,1);
    $this->Ln();
}
//The first parameter of Cell() is the width of the cell.
}
```

Calling snippet

```
$sql="select `station`,`Category`,`Agency`,`startyear` from station";
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$data = $pdf->LoadData($res);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->BasicTable($header,$data);
```

Comment: Please show us code you are using, so that answers can be build up on your solution.

Comment: @etalon11 , I've provided the code

Answer (score 0):

FPDF has a function "GetStringWidth". With that function you can measure the longest text for each column an size the column accordingly to that.

You will find a good example here:
http://fpdf.de/downloads/addons/62/